# Solr: boost based on existence of a field, disregarding that field's contents

Tags: solr

I'd like to boost a query based on the existence of a field in the document, regardless of the contents of that field. Let's say a document has a field containing an id value of a photo, and I'd like documents that have photos to come up first on the search.

The photo id value would be irrelevant to the search query but the existence of the field is what would matter.  How to do it?

Comment: I would store it manually as in `metafield:"hasphotoid hasdate"`, so that it is easily searchable.

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax), `field:[* TO *]` will match all documents with the field and can be used by you for boosting.

With DisMax, `bq` can be used for boosting as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29). Add `<str name="bq">field:[* TO *]^10</str>` to the requestHandler in `solrconfig.xml`

Note that the above does not guarantee all documents with photos will come up at the top followed by documents that don't have photos. However, I think that the above should work well for your use case - please try it out and let me know if you really need guaranteed, absolute ordering.

Comment: I think the asker wants to know how to boost, you might want to complete your answer that way.

Comment: I should have mentioned a couple things: (1) the query is using dismax, and (2) I'm modifying a rails gem and the easiest way would be if I could modify the solrconfig.xml.  For example can I just add something to the existing "qf" section, which already has a list of field names with boost values. Can I have in the defType="dismax" section.  This doesn't seem to work but something like this would be cool:
<str name="qf">
photo_id:[* TO *]^100000
title^50000
text^10000

Comment: Just wanted to add that I got somewhat similar results using
  
bf=ord(my_field)^nnnnnn  
and  
bq=(myfield:[* TO *])^nnnnnn
  
I haven't tested this but I imagine that using bf and ord() uses up some resources doing math, compared with bq as suggested by nikhil, and I'm using the bq boost.  
  
Thanks all!